# Understanding lookbehind

Tags: regex, lookbehind

I put in online testers the regular expression =>  `.{3}(?<=USD\d{3})` and Subject string => USD100 and this returns 100.
I'd like to know is how the regex engine works in this case?
How the regex engine returns this 100?

Regular Expression:
 .{3}(?<=USD\d{3})

Subject:
 USD100

Returns:
 100

Answer (score 1):

Your regex means "three characters" (`.{3}`), plus the additional rule that when you get to the end of the three characters, if you look backward (`(?<=...)`), you will see "USD" plus three digits (`USD\d{3}`).

In your input string (`USD100`), there is only position where you can look backward and see "USD" plus three digits: namely, the very end. So as applied to your input string, your regex effectively means "the three characters just before the very end of the string", i.e. `100`.

Does that make sense?